# Как задать минимальную ширину сайта?

Tags: html, css

Создал страницу для тестирования отображения этой страницы на мобильных устройствах. Указал в `head` `name width=800`, а `wrapper` `min-width: 800px;` и `width: 100%;`.

Проверяю на `android chrome` - браузер не чувствует минимальной ширины `wrapper` и по умолчанию часть страницы за пределами видимости (пример 1), когда требуется, чтобы браузер понимал, какой минимальной ширины страницу ему нужно показать (пример 2).

Как правильно задать минимальную ширину страницы так, чтобы мобильный браузер изначально ее показал, как на примере 2?

**Пример 1:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пример 2:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
html,
body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=800, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
        Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
        Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А зачем вообще вставлять min-width 800px, тем более для мобильной?

Comment: Если честно, то не знаю, вся информация из поиска. Гуглил несколько часов, испробовал кучу вариантов, но решения не нашел...

Comment: удалите min-width и всё, когда вы устанавливаете min-width 800px, понятно что на мобильных wrapper будет выходить за экран. Оставьте только width:100%;

Comment: Тогда каким образом браузер поймет, что нужно отображать страницу шириной минимум 800px?

Comment: на мобильном или десктопной версии нужен min-width?

Comment: страница шириной 800 пикселов будет шире, чем экран мобильного устройства и не влезет

Comment: @Арсен мобильная

Comment: @Heidel браузер может отдалить вид так, чтобы поместилась вся ширина страницы (пример 2)

Comment: Для мобильной не надо никакого min-width. если конечно у вас вся вёрстка не кривая. Если уж так надо вставить, придётся для всех девайсов по отдельности устанавливать min-width через media query

Comment: ок, а как будет выглядеть правильная версия верстки, чтобы результат был, как на примере 2?

Comment: используйте только логику 100% ширины, и вообще зачем в name="viewport" content="width=800 поставили 800 ?

Comment: Я же писал ранее, что вся инфа из поиска, пробовал разные вариант. Вот человек предложил ответ, который так-же не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убрал ширину у `body`; заменил `content="width=800px"` на `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"`.

```
width=device-width
```

нужен для того, чтобы "ширина была равна ширине устройства"

```
shrink-to-fit=no
```

нужен для [запрета масштабирования в соответствии с окном просмотра](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767533/what-does-the-shrink-to-fit-viewport-meta-attribute-do/33949647#33949647)

Добавил [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)-запросы.
Проверьте.

```css
 
@media (min-width: 800px) {
html,
body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: antiquewhite;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
        Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.
        Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В этом варианте работает, но вопрос остался - как задать минимальную ширину сайта? для примера используем 800px

Comment: А @media-запросы использовать? Исправлю ответ с ними, для примера

Comment: У Вас опечатка content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1" > content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"

В остальном все работает. Спасибо!

Получается минимальная ширина страницы реализуется через media запрос?

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Как вариант, `@media` используются для адаптивной верстки, для соответствия размеров экранов и свойств для них. Но да, именно жесткая привязка к минимуму-максимуму реализуется медиа-запросами

Comment: Добавьте в ответ, чтобы масштаб мобильного браузера был равен масштабу минимальной ширины блока, нужно установить: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"> , в противном случае, браузер мобильника всегда будет выставлять масштаб своего дисплея.

Comment: Переработал ответ

Answer (score 1):

Укажите в хедере

```html
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=800px, initial-scale=1">
```

Wrapperу не ничего не указывать(он и так по умолчанию растянется на всю ширину)

Comment: Сделал, не работает.